# Adding to an SVG Map

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have found a map of the UK that I have now personalised.

[Here](https://codepen.io/scottYg55/pen/pooOvWq) is the CodePen.

I now need to add Republic Of Ireland to the map to so it looks like [this](https://www.intersystemsuki.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/map.png) image.

How can I easily do this within the SVG, is there an online generator for example that I could use? Any help is greatly appreciated, I really am not very clued up when it comes to SVGs, thank you all in advance!

I only have enough space to put in limited SVG, please see my codepen.

HTML/SVG

```html
 <div class="svg-map" style="width: 55%;">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="125 100 350 400" style="enable-background:new 125 100 350 400 400;display: block" xml:space="preserve">
        <style type="text/css">
          .whitetext {
            fill: #fff !important;
          }

          .st1 {
            fill: #58B9FA;
          }

          .st2 {
            fill: #0A7FC8;
          }

          .st3 {
            fill: #1B659D;
          }

          .whitegrey {
            fill: #f4f4f4 !important;
          }

          .lightgrey {
            fill: #e6e6e6;
          }

          .darkgrey {
            fill: #848484;
          }

          .midgrey {
            fill: #aeadad;
          }
        </style>
        <g>
          <g>
            <a class="map-link" href="#" data-link="eastanglia">
              <path class="st0 midgrey" d="M426.32,370.36c-0.99-2.68-1.13-4.45-1.48-4.66c-0.35-0.21-2.4-2.33-2.4-2.33l-3.32-1.77l-5.93-3.04
                              c0,0-4.94-1.98-5.37-1.98s-1.91,1.27-1.91,1.27l-5.09-0.85l-4.1,0.35c0,0-2.4,1.55-2.75,2.47c-0.35,0.92-0.85,1.7-0.92,2.33
                              c-0.07,0.64-1.75,2.88-1.75,2.88s-1.25-1.31-1.12-1.53c0.1-0.17-0.91,0.12-1.31,0.24v0.96c0,0-0.77,1.18-1.41,2.18
                              c-0.65,1-2.65,0-2.65,0l-1.36,1.24l-0.94,2.36h-1.65l-1,2.12l-3.48,1.36c0,0-0.18,1.24-2.06,1.77c-1.89,0.53-3-1.47-3-1.47
                              s0.59,1.24,1.24,2c0.65,0.77-0.24,3.25-0.24,3.25l-2.83,2.11l0.29,1l0.29,1.65l-0.71,0.29l-1.06,1.89l-2.24-0.35l0.71,1.53
                              l-1.77,1c0,0-3,1.59-3.77,2.69c-0.77,1.1-2.71,0.61-2.71,0.61l1.41,1.71l-0.74,2.27c0.37,0.24,0.76,0.61,0.88,1.14
                              c0.24,1.07,4.92,3.96,5.95,4.96c1.03,0.99,0.12,2.26,0.04,2.5c-0.08,0.24-3.57-1.03-3.57-1.03l0.99,1.94l2.54,2.02l1.11,2.97
                              l1.51,2.12l-0.02,0l4.81-0.55l3.28-1.48c0,0,3.56-0.51,3.88-0.42s1.2,1.8,1.29,2.03c0.09,0.23,2.59,0.28,2.96,0.37
                              c0.37,0.09,2.64,0.32,2.64,0.32s3.05,1.06,3.47,2.22c0.21,0.58,1.03,1.06,1.81,1.4c0,0-0.01,0.01-0.01,0.02
                              c0.08-0.14,0.15-0.24,0.15-0.24h1.55h2.54l1.77-0.48c0,0,2.19-0.23,3.18-0.01c0.99,0.21,3.39-1.98,3.96-2.26
                              c0.57-0.28,0.35-4.94,0.42-5.37c0.07-0.42-0.78-0.85-1.34-0.28c-0.57,0.57-1.77,0.71-2.19,1.13s-1.77,0.14-2.26,0
                              c-0.49-0.14-0.85-1.2-0.64-1.34c0.21-0.14,2.05,0.07,2.83,0c0.78-0.07,1.55-1.44,1.55-1.44l3.04-2.94c0,0,0.49,1.7,1.7,2.54
                              c1.2,0.85,1.55,0.21,3.67-0.64c2.12-0.85,2.33-3.11,2.33-3.11s-1.84,0.21-2.4,0c-0.56-0.21,1.13-1.2,1.13-1.2l0.92-1.2h-2.97
                              c0,0-2.68-1.06-2.4-1.19c0.28-0.13,0.92-0.08,2.54-0.01c1.62,0.07,2.97-0.44,2.97-0.44s-0.64-0.27-1.2-0.41
                              c-0.57-0.14-1.91-1.2-2.19-1.27c-0.28-0.07-0.21-0.99,0.57-1.13c0.78-0.14,3.6,2.4,3.88,2.68c0.28,0.28,1.2,0,1.2,0l2.61-2.61
                              l2.68-2.83l1.62-3.25l0.14-3.74l1.13-3.04c0,0,1.77-3.96,2.05-5.09C427.59,376.16,427.31,373.05,426.32,370.36z"></path><text class="labels whitetext" x="380" y="390">East Anglia</text>
            </a>
          </g>
          <g>
            <a class="map-link" href="#" data-link="southeast">
              <path class="st1 darkgrey" d="M419.9,422.77c0.35-0.28-1.7-0.35-2.19-0.35c-0.49,0-2.19-0.14-3.46-0.14c-1.27,0-3.04,0.57-3.04,0.57
                                s-2.19,0.35-2.75,0.64c-0.57,0.29-3.39,0-3.39,0s-1.84-0.07-2.9,0c-1.06,0.07-0.07-1.24-0.07-1.24h2.61c0,0,1.55-0.38,1.13-0.38
                                s-2.68-1.84-3.53-2.33c-0.85-0.49-0.28,0.14-0.64,0.42c-0.35,0.28-0.49,0.85-0.49,1.13c0,0.28-0.14,1.06-1.2,1.14
                                c-1.06,0.08-1.77-0.08-2.47-0.01c-0.71,0.07-0.85-0.57-0.85-0.85s0.14-0.99,0.21-1.2c0.07-0.21,1.84-0.42,3.32-0.49
                                c1.48-0.07,0.14-0.28,0.07-0.64c-0.07-0.35-0.92-1.06-2.83-1.27c-1.91-0.21-1.48-0.07-1.77-0.07s-0.78,0.92-0.78,0.92
                                s-1.2,0.07-1.41-0.57c-0.02-0.06-0.06-0.11-0.09-0.16l-0.89,0.89l-2.77,0.14c0,0-1.06,0.05-3.05,0.74s-0.88,2.77-1.43,4.12
                                c-0.55,1.34-0.6,1.34-1.11,1.94c-0.51,0.6-1.39,0-1.48-0.74s-1.39-0.74-2.64-0.46c-1.25,0.28-1.71,1.53-2.17,0.79
                                c-0.46-0.74-0.97-0.79-0.97-0.79s-1.2-1.29-1.71-1.53s-1.43,0.92-1.43,0.92s-0.18-0.92-0.18-1.43c0-0.51-0.92-0.92-2.54-2.36
                                c-1.62-1.43-1.94-1.43-1.94-1.43l-0.42-6.15l0.02,0l-1.51-2.12l-1.11-2.97l-2.54-2.02l-0.99-1.94c0,0,3.49,1.27,3.57,1.03
                                c0.08-0.24,0.99-1.51-0.04-2.5c-1.03-0.99-5.71-3.88-5.95-4.96c-0.24-1.07-1.63-1.51-1.63-1.51l-2.18-1.27l-3.33,1.9
                                c0,0-0.79,1.15-1.74,1.23c-0.95,0.08-3.53-0.24-3.53-0.24l1.15-4.6c0,0-0.67-0.75-1.15-1.15c-0.48-0.4-1.78,0.55-1.78,0.55
                                s-0.4,0.91-1.07,1.31c-0.67,0.4-2.02,3.29-2.38,3.88c-0.36,0.59-2.97,2.46-3.49,3.01c-0.52,0.55-1.23,5.87-1.23,7.29
                                s0.95,0.95,0.75,2.14c-0.2,1.19-1.19,0-0.75,2.26c0.44,2.26,1.15,3.92,1.15,3.92l2.42,2.85l0.83,2.06l-0.75,1.9l1.27,0.4
                                l-0.16,1.47l-1.31,2.5l-1.68,1.51l-2.36-0.2c0,0,0.99,2.5,1.19,4c0.2,1.51,1.55,5.15,1.55,5.15s-0.24,1.43-0.79,2.02
                                c-0.56,0.59-0.67,0.95-1.59,0.63c-0.91-0.32-5.15-2.22-5.95-1.9c-0.79,0.32-1.23,1.39-1.23,1.39l2.5,1.55
                                c0,0,1.55-0.95,1.23,0.32c-0.32,1.27,0.16,2.14,0.16,2.14l0.24,1.07c0,0-0.04,0.62,0.24,1.4s1.07,1.41,1.07,1.41l1.19,1.05
                                c0.11-0.1,0.18-0.18,0.18-0.18l2.38,0.71l1.22-0.64c0,0,1.27-1.06,2.9-1.48s2.61-0.85,2.9-0.99c0.28-0.14-0.42-1.48-0.99-1.77
                                c-0.57-0.28-2.54-2.61-2.54-2.9s3.74,1.55,4.8,2.33c1.06,0.78,3.46,3.25,3.46,3.25v-1.34v-1.7l2.26,0.28l-0.85,1.77v1.55
                                c0,0,0.64-0.78,0.85-0.99c0.21-0.21,0.49-1.84,0.71-2.26c0.21-0.42,1.55-0.07,1.55-0.07l2.05,0.42l0.42,1.62
                                c0,0-0.42,0.71-0.42,0.92c0,0.21,1.2,1.34,1.41,1.34c0.21,0,1.98-0.64,1.98-0.64l1.91-0.78l2.97-1.34l4.87-0.21l5.37-0.99
                                l5.44,1.84l2.75,1.27l3.46,0.85l3.32-3.67c0,0,5.23-0.57,5.79-0.64c0.57-0.07,1.48-1.2,1.48-1.2l1.27-0.64l2.12-2.26
                                c0,0,2.47,0.71,3.46,1.13c0.99,0.42,0.99,0.35,1.41-0.71c0.42-1.06-0.28-1.84,0.64-2.97c0.92-1.13,4.03-2.75,4.03-2.75
                                s3.32-1.7,4.1-1.84c0.78-0.14,2.61-2.47,2.61-2.47s0.57-2.68,0.78-3.6c0.21-0.92-1.06-1.34-1.06-1.34s0.28-1.13,0.42-1.41
                                C418.48,423.76,419.54,423.05,419.9,422.77z"></path><text class="labels whitetext" x="360" y="435">South East</text>
            </a>
          </g>
          <g>
            <g>

              <a class="map-link" href="#">
                <path class="st0" d="M233.09,171.93c0-0.02-0.4-1.05-0.4-0.78s-0.8,1.56-0.8,1.56S233.09,171.94,233.09,171.93z"></path>
              </a>

              <a class="lightgrey map-link" href="#" data-link="scotland">
                <path class="st00" d="M325.51,255.16c-0.37-1.39-3.8-5.38-3.57-6.17c0.23-0.79,1.53-0.09,2.13-0.83c0.6-0.74,1.44-1.39,3.15-3.39
                                c0.89-1.03,2.05-2.24,2.96-3.16l-3.1-4.3l-2.03-0.18c0,0-3.67-1.41-4.46-1.81c-0.8-0.4-2.34-0.8-3.14-1.1
                                c-0.8-0.31-3.49-1.9-3.49-1.9s-2.08-0.66-3.58-0.18c-1.5,0.49-1.5,2.47-2.17,3.14c-0.66,0.66-3.8,1.37-3.8,1.37l-1.9-0.75
                                l-3.71-0.75l-4.68-1.24l-5.08-0.35l-2.3-1.46c0,0-2.17-1.9-2.25-2.03c-0.09-0.13,0.53-1.02,0.53-1.02l3.4,2.25l2.74,0.4
                                c0,0,5.57,0.44,6.23,0.4c0.66-0.04,4.15-0.49,4.15-0.49s0.22-1.46,0.31-1.72c0.09-0.27,4.77-4.24,5.44-4.51
                                c0.66-0.27,1.46-0.31,2.47,0.49c1.02,0.8,1.24,0.44,2.03,0.13c0.8-0.31,3.98-2.61,3.98-2.61s-0.04-1.02-0.09-1.15
                                c-0.04-0.13-1.5-0.88-1.5-0.88s-3.49-1.06-3.62-1.33c-0.13-0.27,0.18-1.59,0.18-1.59l0.22-1.5c0,0-2.43-1.06-3.36-0.57
                                c-0.93,0.49-3.89,2.12-3.89,2.12l-3.45,1.15c0,0-1.81,0.84-1.86,0.4c-0.04-0.44,5.26-4.73,5.26-4.73l4.37-0.53l4.29-0.09
                                l4.51-3.76c0,0,2.17-2.43,2.52-5.35c0.35-2.92,2.7-2.96,3.84-3.62c1.15-0.66,2.83-4.11,2.74-5.35c-0.09-1.24,0.53-3.14,1.06-3.84
                                c0.53-0.71,3.09-2.52,2.61-4.33c-0.49-1.81,1.77-6.67,2.96-7.78c1.19-1.1,3.23-3.45,4.02-4.68c0.8-1.24,1.06-0.4,1.33-0.57
                                c0.27-0.18-0.75-0.71-1.28-2.56c-0.53-1.86-2.96-5.74-2.96-5.74s-3.09-1.28-4.33-1.28s-1.5,0.49-1.5,0.49s-1.28,0.66-2.08,0.62
                                c-0.8-0.04-1.02-0.97-1.24-0.66c-0.22,0.31,0.27,0.62-1.37,0.84c-1.64,0.22-2.34,0.09-4.15-0.35c-1.81-0.44-8.17-0.88-9.15-1.02
                                c-0.97-0.13-2.25,1.33-3.93,1.77c-1.68,0.44-2.47-0.27-3.4-1.15c-0.93-0.88-6.1-1.33-7.11-1.24c-1.02,0.09-0.62,1.1-1.41,2.03
                                c-0.8,0.93-1.68,0.49-1.68,0.49l-0.71,0.71c0,0-1.15-0.84-1.46-0.8c-0.31,0.04-1.72,1.24-2.83,2.47c-1.1,1.24-3,0.18-3,0.18
                                s-3.14-0.22-3.84,0.66c-0.71,0.88-2.7,3.89-2.7,3.89s-2.12-1.37-1.81-2.08c0.31-0.71,2.78-2.47,3.89-3.27
                                c1.1-0.8,1.37-2.25,1.37-2.25c-0.22,0.31-1.81,0.22-1.81,0.22s-2.17-0.18-3.4,0.22c-1.24,0.4-2.65,2.12-2.92,2.43
                                c-0.27,0.31-1.37,0.93-1.33,0.04c0.04-0.88,2.52-3,3.09-3.8c0.57-0.8,2.52-0.22,2.52-0.22s1.86-1.28,3.31-1.99
                                c1.46-0.71,0.75,1.81,1.15,1.9c0.4,0.09,4.51-4.15,4.51-4.15l0.88-2.39c0,0-1.24,1.15-1.99,1.72c-0.75,0.57-0.97,0.27-1.46,0.27
                                c-0.49,0-0.75-0.84-1.02-0.84c-0.27,0-1.19,0.84-1.19,0.84s-2.7-0.62-5.08-0.8c-2.39-0.18-2.92-0.71-2.92-0.71l-0.8-2.03
                                c0,0,1.94,0.44,2.61,0.93c0.66,0.49,2.17,0,4.07,0.13c1.9,0.13,2.34-0.57,2.34-0.57l0.22-1.5c0,0-1.77-0.62-1.37-1.33
                                s1.55,0.18,1.99,0c0.44-0.18,3.18-1.81,4.68-3.27c1.5-1.46,9.9-7.64,11.27-8.93c1.37-1.28,2.3-1.1,3.23-1.59
                                c0.93-0.49,3.45-4.77,3.45-4.77l0.13-1.41c0,0-1.19-1.63-1.19-2.47s2.65-4.07,2.65-4.07s-4.73-0.57-5.13-0.57
                                s-2.08,0.13-2.08,0.13s-1.81-1.15-2.03-0.53c-0.22,0.62,1.28,1.19,1.28,1.19s0,1.1-0.53,1.24c-0.53,0.13-6.1-0.97-6.1-0.97
                                s-2.39,0.4-2.52,0.53c-0.13,0.13-3,1.41-3,1.41s-3.23,0.09-3.62,0.09s-1.15-1.55-1.15-1.55s-0.13,1.06-0.27,1.33
                                c-0.13,0.27-0.13,0.49-1.28,0.66c-1.15,0.18-2.3,1.24-2.43,1.33c-0.13,0.09-3.05-0.84-4.11,0.04c-1.06,0.88-3.23,2.87-3.23,2.87
                                s0.57-1.94,1.15-3.05c0.57-1.1-1.5-1.86-1.63-2.03c-0.13-0.18-1.64-0.09-1.68,0.49c-0.04,0.57-3.8,5.13-3.8,5.13l-0.97-0.88
                                c0,0,2.3-3.27,2.3-3.54c0-0.27-2.3-2.3-2.3-2.3s-0.09,1.59-0.27,2.03c-0.18,0.44-1.02,1.1-1.02,1.1s-0.71-2.83-1.02-3
                                c-0.31-0.18-2.43-1.24-2.43-1.24l-1.81,3.76l-1.72,1.15l1.06,1.02l0.71,1.15l-1.55,0.88l1.77,0.82l-0.09,1.75
                                c0,0-2.83-1.99-3.23-1.72c-0.4,0.27-0.4,2.83-0.4,2.83l2.65,2.7l2.3-0.49l0.18,1.94c0,0-2.78-0.66-2.96-0.62
                                c-0.18,0.04-3.49-0.13-3.49-0.13s-1.19,0.35-2.25,0.66c-1.06,0.31-2.21-0.88-2.21-0.88s0,0,0.13,0.75
                                c0.13,0.75,3.14,2.83,3.54,3.09c0.4,0.27-0.97,2.3-1.02,2.56c-0.04,0.27-0.09,1.28-1.41,1.28c-1.33,0-2.52-0.88-2.52-0.88
                                s0.62,1.72,0.84,2.08c0.22,0.35,1.68,0.97,1.68,0.97l2.52,1.41c0,0,0.93,0.4,0.97,1.48c0.04,1.08,2.65,2.63,2.65,2.63l-1.02,1.41
                                l-1.02-1.28l-1.55-1.28c0,0-2.08-0.57-2.21-0.62c-0.13-0.04-1.9-1.15-2.03-0.8c-0.13,0.35,4.11,2.65,4.11,2.65s0.18,1.24,0,1.24
                                c-0.18,0-4.29-2.78-4.29-2.78s-1.28,1.9-1.9,2.3c-0.62,0.4-0.22-0.13-0.62-0.27c-0.4-0.13-0.93-1.1-0.93-1.1
                                s-1.24-1.41-1.55-1.46c-0.31-0.04-0.71,0.18-1.02,1.28c-0.31,1.1,1.33,1.19,1.59,1.41c0.27,0.22,0.35,2.61,0.31,2.87
                                c-0.04,0.27-1.94,0.4-1.94,0.4l-0.93-0.57c0,0-0.22-2.17-0.31-2.7c-0.09-0.53-1.28-0.66-1.28-0.66s-0.71,0-1.19,0.71
                                c-0.49,0.71-0.22,3.62,0.13,3.93c0.35,0.31,2.61,1.33,2.61,1.33s-0.35,0.71-0.75,1.19c-0.4,0.49-1.15-0.31-1.37-0.35
                                c-0.22-0.04-0.93,1.24-0.93,1.24s-0.09,0.75,0.22,1.1s2.74,3.21,2.74,3.21s2.65,0.06,2.83,0c0.18-0.06,1.06,0.46,1.15,0.94
                                c0.09,0.49-2.12,0.53-2.52,0.53c-0.4,0-1.68,0.35-1.68,0.35l-1.1-0.75c0,0-2.7-1.68-2.74-0.84c-0.04,0.84-0.62,3.31-0.62,3.31
                                l0.93,1.37l-0.09,2.43c0,0,1.15,0.75,1.72,0.75c0.57,0,1.37-1.46,1.37-1.46l0.97-0.57l1.02,0.31l-0.49,1.1
                                c0,0,0.84,0.18,1.59,0.22c0.75,0.04,1.1-0.97,1.1-0.97l1.28-1.24l1.28,0.44c0,0-0.84,1.28-1.1,1.64c-0.27,0.35-1.9,1.1-2.52,1.28
                                c-0.62,0.18-2.17-0.53-2.3-0.53c-0.13,0-1.94,2.12-1.94,2.12l2.03,0.35l1.99,0.35l2.61-1.99l1.15,0.31c0,0,0,0,0.09,0.62
                                c0.09,0.62-1.86,0.8-1.9,1.37c-0.04,0.57,1.77,1.33,1.77,1.33l0.18,0.71c0,0-1.37,0-1.94-0.35c-0.57-0.35-1.59-0.75-2.25-0.71
                                s-0.35,0.53-0.88,1.59c-0.53,1.06-1.63,1.1-1.63,1.1l1.28,1.5c0,0,1.55,0.66,2.25,0.93c0.71,0.27,3.18-0.35,3.18-0.35l-0.13,1.24
                                l-0.35,0.13l-2.3-0.04l-2.7-0.53h-2.08l-1.55,1.28l-0.13,0.88l1.9,0.35c0,0,0.93,1.33,1.64,1.81c0.71,0.49,2.47,0,2.47,0
                                s-0.04,0.49-0.84,0.97c-0.8,0.49-1.63,0.09-2.52,0.44c-0.88,0.35-2.43-2.56-3.14-1.94c-0.71,0.62-2.7,4.42-2.78,4.78
                                c-0.09,0.37,1.19,0.25,1.63,0.3c0.44,0.04,1.06-0.04,1.72-0.27c0.66-0.22,0,0.75,0.22,0.8c0.22,0.04,2.34-0.31,2.34,0
                                c0,0.31-0.88,0.49-1.24,0.84c-0.35,0.35-3,0.62-3.49,1.06c-0.49,0.44,0.88,0.84,1.06,0.93c0.18,0.09-0.35,0.75-0.66,1.9
                                c-0.31,1.15-0.88,0-1.81-0.31c-0.93-0.31-1.86-0.57-2.87,0c-1.02,0.57-2.03-0.04-3.18,0.09c-1.15,0.13-2.25,1.55-2.25,1.55
                                s0.04,1.06,0.22,1.41c0.18,0.35,1.37-0.44,1.86-0.53c0.49-0.09,6.27,0.62,6.27,0.62l1.94-0.22l1.24-0.93l2.7,0.84
                                c0,0,1.55,1.06,0.75,1.28c-0.8,0.22-1.06-0.35-1.06-0.35l-1.59-0.04l-2.21,0.18l-1.41,1.02l-1.41-0.66l-2.08,1.06
                                c0,0,4.9,3.45,5.04,3.31c0.13-0.13,1.02-0.97,1.02-0.97l0.04,1.28c0,0,2.7,1.33,3,1.28c0.31-0.04,8.93-8.31,9.63-8.84
                                c0.71-0.53,3.31-3.14,3.31-2.25c0,0.88-2.12,2.65-1.77,3.18c0.35,0.53,5.3-0.71,4.6,0.22c-0.71,0.93-5.26,1.02-5.97,1.28
                                c-0.71,0.27-3.53,4.27-3.53,4.27s-1.39,2.27-1.64,2.9c-0.25,0.63,1.29,0.4,2.32,0.55c1.03,0.15,3.1,0.45,3.6,0.2
                                c0.5-0.25,3.6-3.12,3.6-3.12c-0.08,0.63-2.12,3.2-2.55,3.58c-0.43,0.38-1.26,0.91-1.26,0.91l-5.67-0.15l-1.36,1.03
                                c0,0-1.49,0.43-1.44,1.08c0.05,0.65,1.67,0,1.67,0l-1.16,1.28l-1.12,2.04c0,0-1.16,1.4-1.92,2.56c-0.76,1.16-0.12,2.24,0.08,2
                                c0.2-0.24,2.4-2.85,2.4-2.85l1.12-0.32l0.68,0.64c0,0-1.04,0.44-1.56,1c-0.52,0.56-1.6,3.45-1.6,3.45l2-1.64
                                c0,0,0,0.96-0.12,1.13c-0.12,0.17-0.08,1.48-0.72,2.08c-0.64,0.6-2.32,2.56-2.93,3.73c-0.6,1.16-0.68,2.48-0.36,2
                                s2.6-3.21,2.6-3.21s0.4,0.68,0.56,1.4c0.16,0.72-2.11,1.84-2.7,2.52c-0.59,0.68-0.59,2.11-0.59,2.11l2.03-1.94l0.68,1.01
                                c0,0-1.86,1.01-2.7,2.2c-0.84,1.18,0.59,2.37,0.59,2.37s0.68,0.93,1.18,0.99c0.51,0.06,0.84-0.15,1.27-0.4
                                c0.42-0.25,1.52-2.53,1.77-2.62c0.25-0.08,0.93,0.84,1.01,1.69c0.08,0.84-1.44,1.35-2.45,2.2c-1.01,0.84-1.52,1.35-2.7,2.7
                                c-1.18,1.35-0.42,1.52-0.59,2.37c-0.17,0.84-1.1,1.77-1.1,1.77s-0.17,4.48-0.34,5.32c-0.17,0.84-0.93,1.35-1.1,1.77
                                c-0.17,0.42-1.1,1.69-1.01,2.87c0.08,1.18,0.68,1.94,1.35,1.52c0.68-0.42,2.87-0.84,2.87-0.84s1.86-1.18,2.2-2.37
                                c0.34-1.18-0.68-1.27-0.68-1.27s-0.42-1.18-0.08-1.86c0.34-0.68,1.44-3.46,1.44-3.46s0.76-3.63,1.18-5.41
                                c0.42-1.77,4.14-3.97,4.14-4.56c0-0.59-3.46-5.66-3.46-5.66s-0.17-2.2,0.25-2.87c0.42-0.68,1.44-0.42,1.44-0.42l3.04-2.86
                                c0,0,2.53-2.46,2.79-2.87c0.25-0.41,1.69-1.53,2.03-2.12c0.34-0.59,3.97-2.45,3.97-2.45l0.34,0.59c0,0-2.03,2.11-2.37,2.79
                                c-0.34,0.68-4.31,3.72-4.31,3.72s-3.21,2.37-3.8,5.32c-0.59,2.96,0.42,3.63,0.42,3.63s1.69,0.76,1.69,0.51
                                c0-0.25,0.59-1.94,0.59-1.94l0.93-1.86l0.76,1.18h1.35l-1.1-3.8l1.52,1.44l0.42,2.7l1.77,2.03c0,0,1.27-2.11,1.52-2.62
                                c0.25-0.51-0.17-1.18-0.25-1.6c-0.08-0.42,1.1-0.76,1.1-0.76l-0.17-3.88l0.51-3.3l0.93,1.77c0,0,0.42-0.17,0.76-1.34
                                c0.34-1.17,1.86-1.19,1.86-1.19l-1.77,3.46l-0.25,1.69c0,0,3.97,2.53,4.31,3.29c0.34,0.76,4.65,1.69,4.39,1.77
                                c-0.25,0.08-5.32,0.25-5.32,0.25s-2.53-0.84-3.63-0.84c-1.1,0-0.84,2.62-0.84,2.62s0.25,4.22-0.08,5.58
                                c-0.34,1.35-0.76,1.1-0.68,1.35c0.08,0.25,4.05,3.21,4.05,3.21s1.27,1.86,1.27,2.11s1.86,2.7,1.86,2.7s-1.27,2.53-1.77,2.96
                                c-0.51,0.42-4.14,3.72-4.14,3.72l0.25,4.14c0,0-3.38,3.21-4.65,4.69c-1.27,1.48-0.76,4.98-0.76,4.98l1.06,3.67
                                c0,0-1.06,0.35-1.62,0.07c-0.57-0.28-1.98-4.17-1.98-4.17s-1.13,1.13-1.2,3.25c-0.07,2.12,0,2.05,0,2.05l2.97,4.03l2.19,1.84
                                c0,0,0.07,1.77,0.21,2.97c0.14,1.2,1.13,0.92,1.13,0.92s0.92,0,1.06-1.38c0.14-1.38-2.61-4.84-2.61-4.84l0.92-1.7
                                c0,0,1.34-0.85,2.12-1.06c0.78-0.21,2.33,0.99,2.33,0.99s3.81,2.33,4.94,3.11c1.13,0.78,1.77,2.05,1.77,2.05s2.54,1.34,2.75,1.45
                                c0.21,0.11,0.49-3.43,0.49-3.43s-0.42-1.84-0.78-1.91c-0.35-0.07-0.85-1.13-0.85-1.34c0-0.21,0.21-1.55,0.42-1.91
                                c0.21-0.35,0.78-0.28,1.13-0.28c0.35,0,2.12,2.61,2.12,2.61l0.85-0.78c0,0,1.77-0.35,1.77,0.21c0,0.57,0.42,1.55,0.42,1.55
                                l1.55,1.27l0.85-1.7l0.71,0.21l1.06,1.91c0,0,2.05-0.92,3.39-1.55c1.34-0.64,0.92-1.13,0.92-1.13l0.78-1.48
                                c0,0,4.31-0.49,5.09-0.49c0.78,0,0.42-1.2,0.49-1.55c0.07-0.35,0.14-1.62,0.99-2.4c0.85-0.78,1.77-0.21,1.98,0
                                c0.19,0.19,6.63,0.03,7.69,0l3.63-1.29l0.19-1.9l2.83,0.37c0,0,0.56-1.53,1.76-2.41c1.21-0.88,1.44-2.37,2.88-2.97
                                c1.44-0.6,2.41-1.3,2.5-1.81c0.09-0.51-0.65-1.3,1.21-2.74c1.85-1.44,2.6-2.88,3.94-2.88c1.34,0,0.97,1.16,2.09,0
                                c1.11-1.16,0.23-1.72,2.32-2.37S325.88,256.55,325.51,255.16z"></path><text class="labels" x="270" y="200">Scotland</text>
              </a>
            </g>
          </g>
          <g>
            <a class="map-link lightgrey" href="#" data-link="london">
              <path class="st2 lightgrey" d="M392.49,418.77l0.89-0.89c-0.33-0.4-1.18-0.14-1.18-0.34c0-0.15,0.37-0.78,0.57-1.12
                              c-0.78-0.34-1.6-0.82-1.81-1.4c-0.42-1.16-3.47-2.22-3.47-2.22s-2.27-0.23-2.64-0.32c-0.37-0.09-2.87-0.14-2.96-0.37
                              c-0.09-0.23-0.97-1.94-1.29-2.03s-3.88,0.42-3.88,0.42l-3.28,1.48l-4.81,0.55l0.42,6.15c0,0,0.32,0,1.94,1.43
                              c1.62,1.43,2.54,1.85,2.54,2.36c0,0.51,0.18,1.43,0.18,1.43s0.92-1.16,1.43-0.92s1.71,1.53,1.71,1.53s0.51,0.05,0.97,0.79
                              c0.46,0.74,0.92-0.51,2.17-0.79c1.25-0.28,2.54-0.28,2.64,0.46s0.97,1.34,1.48,0.74c0.51-0.6,0.55-0.6,1.11-1.94
                              c0.55-1.34-0.55-3.42,1.43-4.12s3.05-0.74,3.05-0.74L392.49,418.77z"></path><text class="labels" x="370" y="418">London</text>
            </a>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: You could load it into an SVG editor such as Inkscape. Not sure how easy its going to be to draw Ireland.

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://d-maps.com/pays.php?num_pay=218

Comment: I use adobe illustrator for such a purpose.

Answer (score -1):

> [...] is there an [SVG] generator [...] ?

Yes, there are several.

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) is an open-source vector graphics editor (licensed under the GPL), widely used and a consistently reliable tool for transforming raster images into SVG files.

You can open a PNG / GIF etc. image (in this case, a map of the British Isles) in **Inkscape** and use

- `Path > Trace Bitmap`

to start converting the image into an SVG file.

When you have finished editing, you can `Save as SVG`.

Finally, you can edit the resulting `.svg` file in a text editor, to produce your final, optimised SVG.

I have used this approach on numerous occasions to turn a bitmap image into a vector image.